# Laravel combined OR AND Solution

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to do select as the following

```
select * from table where (x = 1 OR y = 1) AND starting_at < '2018-05-01'
```

How to do that please.

Comment: What have you tried so far that doesn't work?

Comment: use laravel (Query Builder)[https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DB::table('tableName') 
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where('x', '=', 1)
                      ->orWhere('y', '=', '1');
            })
            ->where('starting_at', '<', '2018-05-01')
            ->get();
```